# Unable to change source branch in GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I have created a simple web site for GitHub Pages. The source of the site is in the "master" branch and the generated web site (what I want to see published) is under the "gh-pages" branch.

[image: Branches]

I was expecting to be able to change the source of the site in the settings. However, the setting is grayed out? I cannot change it (see screenshot below). What am I doing wrong? How do I switch to the "gh-pages" branch?

[image]

Comment: Did you find any fix for this issue?

Comment: Current way is too limited. For instance, I've just changed my main branch from `master` to `v1`, but doc can only be generated from `master` branch, even if the branch doesn't exist. 

I wish it would allow to build a site doc, per branch. That'd be awesome for documenting versions and be able to preview new releases that aren't in master branch yet.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Personal or organization sites are built from `master`. `gh-pages` branch is used to build sites for projects.

As far as I can see, you're using https://user-name.github.io/ url, this is a personal one, so that's why `master` branch is the default one.

See the [documentation page](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)

> If your site is a User or Organization Page that has a repository named `<username>.github.io` or `<orgname>.github.io`, **you cannot publish your site's source files from different locations**. User and Organization Pages that have this type of repository name are only published from the master branch.

So the answer is No, you can not change it. You'll have to adjust your workflow and keep development in another branch (let's call it `development`) and merge to `master` when you're ready to publish.

**UPD:** It's 2020 out there, so as of [July 31st](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-31-build-and-deploy-github-pages-from-any-branch-beta/) GitHub Pages allow you to configure any branch to act as an old `master`

[image: GitHub pages build branch selector]

Comment: Thank you @Anton for the details. I was hoping to be able to have the site source under master and the generated site under gh-pages. It looks like I misunderstood how this works.

Comment: has anybody found a way around this?

Comment: what if i want to deploy from root /docs folder? where static files are built for a vue.js project

Comment: Here from 2020, my problem was that I had made a repo this name "<username>.github.io", and github settings was forcing me to only stay on the master. I went and changed the name of my repository to something that did not have "github.io" at the end, and then I was able to switch over. Only thing now is that the content moved over to https://<username>.github.io/<newname-for-repo>/ .

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, this is the setup I used for publishing a personal page (i.e. `https://user-name.github.io`) using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org) and [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages):

1. Create a different default branch in your repo to work in (e.g. `develop`)
2. Build a static export of your site: `next build && next export`
3. Put a `.nojekyll` marker file in the export directory: `touch out/.nojekyll`
4. Upload the static export to the master branch: `gh-pages -t -b master -d out`

You can bundle these commands in `package.json` to get a convenient `yarn deploy` command:

```
scripts: {
  ...
  "build": "next build",
  "export": "yarn run build && next export",
  "deploy": "yarn export && touch out/.nojekyll && gh-pages -t -b master -d out"
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you are using [`angular-cli-ghpages`](https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages) it will by default create a new branch `gh-pages` and publish to it.

Now as a starter, like me, if you are using **https://user-name.github.io/** and you want your app to be published from the master branch of your **`user-name.github.io`** you can follow the below steps.

1. Make a production ready build using

   ```
   ng build --prod --base-href "/user-name.github.io/"
   ```
2. Deploy to the *master* using `angular-cli-ghpages` using

   ```
   angular-cli-ghpages --branch=master
   ```

Hope this helps.