# Pushing Changes in master branch to gh-pages branch

Tags: github-pages

I started a repo yesterday and have been apparently pushing all of my changes to the master branch and not the gh-pages branch, which still thinks it hasn't been updated since yesterday. How to I get both branches on the same page?

Not sure if this is relevant, but while I have the branches on GitHub, I don't have them on the repo itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just some wording. A repo is where your code is, and it has different branches. When you push to a branch it pushes to the repo.

You can switch branches locally via the command line using

$ git checkout otherBranch

Also, I believe that Github pages hosts the website based on the code on your master branch.

You might find this useful:
[Unable to change source branch in GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978856/unable-to-change-source-branch-in-github-pages)